# I/O redirection using the shell scripting

Tags: shell

I was writing a sheel scripting to print the 7th column of the output from an executable

```
   get_events -r > f
   awk '{print $7}' f > k
   while read h
   do
           fsstat $h
   done <k
```

I need to directly execute the command fsstat which takes the i/p from the o/p derived with the get_events.
How to get the command fsstat executed without involving the storage on files(f and h) as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get_events -r | awk '{print $7}' | while read h; do
    fsstat "$h"
done
```

Another if you're using bash:

```
while read h; do
    fsstat "$h"
done < <(get_events -r | awk '{print $7}')
```

And this one would prevent `fsstat` from eating up input:

```
while read -u 4 h; do
    fsstat "$h"
done 4< <(get_events -r | awk '{print $7}')
```

#### Update

And here's another portable way in which you don't have to use `awk`:

```
get_events -r | while read _ _ _ _ _ _ h _; do
    fsstat "$h"
done
```

Comment: Thanks . < is for reading from a file , can you please explain, why do we  do << as in < <(get_events -r | awk '{print $7}').

Comment: @Angus: that's reading the output of the process. and that's the syntax.

Comment: It's not `<<`. It's `<[space]<()`. See [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

Comment: +1 for the underscored version. it's like haskell's pattern matching. love it.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine this script into one:

```
while IFS=' ' read -ra arr; do
   fsstat "${arr[6]}"
done < <(get_events -r)
```

1. This script is using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) here `< <(get_events -r)` to read from the 
   output of command `get_events -r`
2. Each line of your command's output is read into an array `array` using `read -a`
3. Then from the read array we are using `${arr[6]}` which is 7th index since it starts with `0`.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. I'm beginner to shell scripting. It would be helpful, if you explain what the script does on each line